# C++ How do I find the value in the external program pointer address?

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to find the value in 0x109B74 + 0xF8. Where did I get it wrong and how should I correct it? Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA("AssaultCube", NULL);
    DWORD procID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);
    void* Pointeraddress;
    void* ptr;


    while (1)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)0x109B74, &Pointeraddress, 4, 0);
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)Pointeraddress, &ptr, 4, 0);
        cout << ptr << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely 110% sure that `sizeof(void*)` is 4 on your target platform?

Comment: yes it is 32bit

Comment: Try being more specific than just saying that something is wrong. What happens that shouldn't, or doesn't that should? (A useful first step towards a working program is usually to verify that system calls actually succeed. Then you can start figuring out why they fail.)

Comment: You should show the error, and identify your compiler and version

Comment: You are asking for too many rights from `OpenProcess()`, you only need `PROCESS_VM_READ`.  Also, you are not adding `0xF8` to the read pointer. And where are you getting `0x109B74` from? Is that supposed to be the base address itself of the process, or is that supposed to be relative to the base address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x109B74 is a relative offset, not an absolute address.  It needs to be added to the base address of the module at runtime.

There are other issues with your code, but the best solution is to replace it all with this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <vector>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const char* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    //Get ProcId of the target process
    DWORD procId = GetProcId("ac_client.exe");

    //Getmodulebaseaddress
    uintptr_t moduleBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, "ac_client.exe");

    //Get Handle to Process
    HANDLE hProcess = 0;
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, procId);

    uintptr_t pointer = moduleBase + 0x109B74;

    uintptr_t objectBaseAddr = 0;

    while (1)
    {

        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)pointer, &objectBaseAddr, sizeof(pointer), 0);

        uintptr_t healthAddr = objectBaseAddr + 0xF8;

        int healthValue = 0;

        ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)healthAddr, &healthValue, sizeof(healthValue), 0);

        std::cout << "Health : " << healthValue << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Be sure to follow my tutorials to avoid making mistakes or learning the improper way to do things.